# Error 58031 connecting to a DB2 database

Tags: db2-connect

I have created a database in DB2. It was working until yesterday, but now I am getting the following error when attempting to connect to the database:

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1031N  The database directory cannot be 
found on the indicated file system.  SQLSTATE=58031

Explanation: 

The system database directory or local database directory could not be
found. A database has not been created or it was not cataloged
correctly.

The command cannot be processed.

User response: 

Verify that the database is created with the correct path specification.
The Catalog Database command has a path parameter which specifies the
directory where the database resides.

sqlcode: -1031

sqlstate: 58031
```

What is the cause of the error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

See if the database folder where your actual database files exist has been renamed or moved.

Comment: u need to check for $DB2DIR value also

Answer (score -1):

It might be a license problem. Trying re-installing the license if any.